# Should down voting on closed questions still result in reputation loss?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign

I just down voted a couple rather poor and thankfully closed questions on P.SE when I noticed that my reputation did not decrease from these votes. Should reputation not still be removed for a down vote, considering these votes still affect the question's Op?

I understand that in such a case, the question has already been deemed unacceptable, but I'm not sure it's fair that users would be able to affect another users reputation without this negatively reflecting on their own.

Perhaps this has already been discussed somewhere. It did not show up under "Related Questions" as I was opening this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a recent change done mostly on a trial basis to see how it performs. And it's all questions, not just those that have been closed. The idea is that we want to encourage voting on questions in general and using downvotes as a means of quality control.

More [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free) on Meta.SO.

Comment: Thanks for that. I wasn't aware of this new new trial.